# Twitter API token expiring when using TwitterOAuth

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, twitter

I'm using the library from [MunGell/Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/MunGell/Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth)

I have developed a login that works for an individual user where I store the access token details and then call the login using the sample code on the site:

```
$this->load->library('twitteroauth');

$connection = $this->twitteroauth->create($consumer, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);

$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

The error message I get is `Invalid or expired token`.

I am aware that this is a common error, but I am stumped as I can log a user in if I follow the OAuth process for an individual user and request access, but cannot gain access if I already have the access token. Why is the token no longer valid?

Comment: I am storing (in a db) what comes back from step 7 and I then use this access token and secrect in subsequent connections.

Comment: Please make that comment into an answer and I will mark it as correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely receiving the `invalid or expired token` error because your authorization is just a temporary one. You should check out https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth particularly **Step 7** which explains how to request a longer lasting token.